# How do i aggregate two web services using multithreading?

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services

There are two web services running in an application that provides real-time inventory. I have to write a java multi threaded program to read the inventory from these two interfaces and calculate the total inventory.

Pre-condition : Both the threads has to be started without any delay.

I have tried approaching this problem using the below code. Please check and let me know if this is correct. Also is there another alternative approach available.

```
package com.app.thread;

public class InventoryThread {

    public static void main(String a[]) throws InterruptedException {

        Inventory inv = new Inventory();
        InventoryInterface1 i1 = new InventoryInterface1(inv);
        InventoryInterface2 i2 = new InventoryInterface2(inv);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(i1, "T1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(i2, "T2");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();

        System.out.println(inv.getInventory());
    }
}

class Inventory {

    private long inventory;

    public long getInventory() {
        return inventory;
    }

    public void setInventory(long inventory) {
        this.inventory = inventory;
    }
}

class InventoryInterface1 implements Runnable {

    private Inventory inv;

    public InventoryInterface1(Inventory inv) {
        this.inv = inv;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " running");
        synchronized (inv) {            
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " updates inventory");
            inv.setInventory(inv.getInventory() + 100);         
        }
    }
}

class InventoryInterface2 implements Runnable {
    private Inventory inv;

    public InventoryInterface2(Inventory inv) {
        this.inv = inv;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " running");
        synchronized (inv) {
            try {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " waiting..");
                while(inv.getInventory() <= 0){
                    inv.wait();
                }               
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " updates inventory");
            inv.setInventory(inv.getInventory() + 200);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " notifies");
            inv.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest you read a concurrency tutorial first. There are a few things wrong in your example that in essense require a tutorial like answer

Comment: @loannis I am learning concurrency in java and wanted to get experts inputs for the problem i was asked to solve. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Inventory.inventory` to `AtomicLong`. That way you wont need syncronization on  `Inventory` instance in `InventoryInterface1 & InventoryInterface2`

```
class Inventory {

    private AtomicLong inventory = new AtomicLong();

    public long getInventory() {
        return inventory.longValue();
    }

    public void incrementInventory(long inventory) {
        inventory.addAndGet(inventory);
    }
}
```

Problem is that reads and writes to `long` in `Java` are not required to be atomic. AtomicLong's `addAndGet` is an atomic operation.

Here are modified `InventoryInterface1` and `InventoryInterface2`

```
class InventoryInterface1 implements Runnable {

    private Inventory inv;

   public InventoryInterface1(Inventory inv) {
        this.inv = inv;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " running");
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " updates  inventory");
        inv.incrementInventory(100);         

    }
}



  class InventoryInterface2 implements Runnable {

    private Inventory inv;

    public InventoryInterface2(Inventory inv) {
        this.inv = inv;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " running");
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " updates inventory");
        inv.incrementInventory(200);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is helpful. AtomicLong object needs to be created in the Inventory class to avoid Null pointer exception. Thanks.

Comment: Updated the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you will see any performance improvement from multithreading if both of your `Runnable` threads are synchronized for their entire execution since only one can be active at a time. The general approach looks correct though, I would just try to limit your synchronization to when you are actually accessing shared memory.

**Update**

It looks like you may also have a deadlock situation where one of the threads is holding the synchronization lock and also waiting for the other thread which can't execute until the lock is freed. You could release the lock before you call `inv.wait()`, but really you should just use a finer grained synchronization around the accesses to `inv`.

Do you actually care which thread executes first? If you do you might not want to use multi-threading, if you don't you can likely remove the `wait()` from `InventoryInterface2`.

```
class InventoryInterface2 implements Runnable {
    private Inventory inv;

    public InventoryInterface2(Inventory inv) {
        this.inv = inv;
   }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " running");
        synchronized (inv) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " updates inventory");
        inv.setInventory(inv.getInventory() + 200);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " notifies");
        inv.notifyAll();
    }

}
```

Comment: I added wait() for inter thread communication, so that deadlock does not occur. I ran your changes and it works too. Thanks.